# Best method if Odoo and mobile app communication

Tags: api, odoo, xml-rpc, endpoint

We wanted to create a mobile app using flutter, I searched on how to connect odoo with external platforms or apps , I found there are two solutions:

The most common and standard one is to use the xmlrpc communication protocol, we did found some libraries with that name in flutter , but the problem with this is that it's a bit complicated for flutter devs that does not know how the Odoo architecture works.

The least common method is the endpoints or controllers method, basically you create endpoints in your controllers and just call it through http request from the mobile side, the problem with this method is that it's not standard and I did not see much people talk about it, I also heard that this method is for the web instead of mobile apps since the session_id of the identification is returned in the Cookies.

My question is the following, is the endpoint method good enough for mobile app? If no, are their any alternative of xmlrpc?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect odoo with the flutter app using simple RESTful API requests, there are many packages in pub.dev which can help you